# Know if my phone has IR blaster

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

How do I know if my android has a built-in IR blaster for remote control? It isn't a high-end phone, but was built in June 2014

my own is a Huawei ascend g610, but I'd like to know the procedure for every phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a small led in the phone if it has got IR Blaster. Also you can look in this List of smartphones that has got IR Blaster http://www.akshatblog.com/list-of-android-smartphones-with-ir-blaster/